# What is an instance variable in Java?

Tags: java, instance-variables

My assignment is to make a program with an instance variable, a string, that should be input by the user. But I don't even know what an instance variable is. What is an instance variable?

How do I create one? What does it do?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Instance variable is the variable declared inside a class, but outside a method: something like:

```
class IronMan {

    /** These are all instance variables **/
    public String realName;
    public String[] superPowers;
    public int age;

    /** Getters and setters here **/
}
```

Now this IronMan Class can be instantiated in another class to use these variables. Something like:

```
class Avengers {

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        IronMan ironman = new IronMan();
        ironman.realName = "Tony Stark";
        // or
        ironman.setAge(30);
    }

}
```

This is how we use the instance variables. Shameless plug: This example was pulled from this free e-book here [here](http://www.confusedcoders.com/java/confusedcoders-java-interview-preparation-ebook).

Answer (score 31):

An instance variable is a variable that is a member of an instance of a class (i.e., associated with something created with a `new`), whereas a class variable is a member of the class itself.

Every instance of a class will have its own copy of an instance variable, whereas there is only one of each static (or class) variable, associated with the class itself.

*[What’s the difference between a class variable and an instance variable?](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/whats-the-difference-between-a-class-variable-and-an-instance-variable/)*

This test class illustrates the difference:

```
public class Test {
   
    public static String classVariable = "I am associated with the class";
    public String instanceVariable = "I am associated with the instance";
    
    public void setText(String string){
        this.instanceVariable = string;
    }
    
    public static void setClassText(String string){
        classVariable = string;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test1 = new Test();
        Test test2 = new Test();
        
        // Change test1's instance variable
        test1.setText("Changed");
        System.out.println(test1.instanceVariable); // Prints "Changed"
        // test2 is unaffected
        System.out.println(test2.instanceVariable); // Prints "I am associated with the instance"
        
        // Change class variable (associated with the class itself)
        Test.setClassText("Changed class text");
        System.out.println(Test.classVariable); // Prints "Changed class text"
        
        // Can access static fields through an instance, but there still is only one
        // (not best practice to access static variables through instance)
        System.out.println(test1.classVariable); // Prints "Changed class text"
        System.out.println(test2.classVariable); // Prints "Changed class text"
    }
}
```

Comment: correct. You can also think of an instance variable as a `field` in an object. A relevant concept is encapsulation (see: `private` access modifier, getters and setters...)

Comment: Indeed, i have declared most things public for easy access, this is usually a bad idea