# how to store array in a recursive function?

Tags: java, arrays, permutation

I have a permutation recursive array which works fine but I need to store the result not just print them out,I have to store each print out in a separate array or the whole in one array

here is the original:

```
public static void Permute(String soFar, String rest)  
        {  
           if (rest.isEmpty())  
           {
               System.out.println(soFar);  

           }           
            else  
           {  
               for (int i =0; i < rest.length(); i++)  
                {  
                    String next = soFar + rest.charAt(i);  
                    String remaining  = rest.substring(0,i) + rest.substring(i+1);  
                    Permute(next,remaining);  
                }  
           }  
        }
```

and I changed it but the problem is that return arr is not proper in there I should do something else
because the arr would become empty because other recursive function would be called and I don't want it

```
public static String Permute(String soFar, String rest,String arr)  
    {  
       if (rest.isEmpty())  
       {
        //   System.out.println(soFar);  
       arr+=soFar;
       }           
        else  
       {  
           for (int i =0; i < rest.length(); i++)  
            {  
                String next = soFar + rest.charAt(i);  
                String remaining  = rest.substring(0,i) + rest.substring(i+1);  
                Permute(next,remaining,arr);  
            }  
       }  
    return arr;
    }
```

Comment: Can you not use a List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `arr` parameter to be a List. Then instead of the println() just keep adding to this List. Also, when you call permute for the first time, make sure you pass in an allocated List. Like so:

```
public void ParentFunction()
{
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    Permute(..., ..., results);
    // Now you have all results inside "results" variable.
}

public static void Permute(String soFar, String rest, List<String> results)  
{
    if (rest.isEmpty())  
    {
        //System.out.println(soFar);  
        results.add(soFar); // ADD TO RESULT LIST
    }           
    else  
    {  
        for (int i = 0; i < rest.length(); i++)  
        {  
            String next = soFar + rest.charAt(i);  
            String remaining  = rest.substring(0, i) + rest.substring(i + 1);  
            Permute(next, remaining, results);  
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you buddy,quick neat explained

Comment: @Nickparsa You should use the least specific interface necessary to accept a parameter or declare a variable. Your edit for the `new ArrayList<String>` part was correct, but otherwise, your edits introduced bad practices.

Comment: @Corbin it gave me error when I used his so I changed it if you know how to edit please do it so everybody will see the correct one

Comment: @Nickparsa Just the `new ArrayList<String>()` needed to be changed - the rest can remain as `List`. I've updated your update :)

Answer (score 1):

One way;

1. Create an instance variable of type List: `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();`
2. Replace `System.out.println(soFar);` with `myList.add(soFar);`
3. Probably in the end convert your list to an array: `String[] arr = (String[]) myList.toArray();`

Comment: where should I create the list? if I create it in the first line every time it will be renewed?

Comment: You can create it as an [instance (class level) variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686488/java-what-is-an-instance-variable) so that it's just instantiated once