# "constants" vs "instance variable" with respect to interface

Tags: java

what is the difference between **constants** and **instance variables** in java?Which one of the them is allowed to be defined in an interface? Examples would help.

Comment: Have you done your research?

Comment: [constants variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-constants-in-java), [instance variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686488/java-what-is-an-instance-variable) and [your question](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+instance+variable+interface) The first link right out gives you the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to Interface.
Any "field" you declare in an interface will be a public static final field. In other words, a constant.
There is no instance variable in interface
If you try to make it protected, it will fail because it would become protected static final, which is not allowed inside interfaces.

If you see something like this and is confused

```
public interface SampleInterface
{
  int i = 123;
  public void display();
}
```

The Java Complier makes that code like this

```
public interface SampleInterface
{
    public static final int i = 123;

    public abstract void display();
}
```

Every field in an interface is public, static and final, even if you omit one or more of the modifiers.

Every method in an interface is public and abstract, even if you omit one or more of the modifiers.