# How can I create an array of objects without creating extra instance variables?

Tags: java, arrays, instance-variables

I am trying to solve the following question:

> Implement a class called TriangleArray which has the following:
> No other instance variables or constants allowed.
>
> 1. An instance variable called list which is an array of Triangle objects.
> 2. No other instance variables or constants allowed.
> 3. Only one constructor which has two integer parameters. The first parameter called number is
>    the length of list. The second parameter called maxSize is the maximum size allowed for the
> 4. The constructor initializes list to an array of Triangle objects.
> 5. The sides of each Triangle object are randomly generated integers in the range from 1 to
>    maxSize.
> 6. Getter and setter methods for list.
> 7. A largest method with no parameters. The method returns the largest Triangle in list.
> 8. A toString method which returns a description of each Triangle in list.

How can I populate the list full of random objects without using other instance variable?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class TriangleArray
{
  private Triangle[ ] list;
  // list is an array of "number" Triangle objects.   
  // The maximum size of each Triangle edge is "maxSize".
  public TriangleArray (int number,  int maxSize);
  {
    list = new Triangle[number];
```

Comment: Why do you think you need other instance variables? Local variables in the function should do.

Comment: how about `list[0] = new Triangle()`?

Comment: some reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686488/java-what-is-an-instance-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the local variables in functions.

```
public TriangleArray (int number,  int maxSize) {
    list = new Triangle[number];
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < number; list[i] = makeRandomTriangle(random, maxSize);
}

private function makeRandomTriangle(Random random, int maxSize) {
    int a = random.nextInt(maxSize) + 1,
        b = random.nextInt(maxSize) + 1;

    // |a - b| <= c <= (a + b) because of the triangle inequality
    int min = Math.max(a - b, b - a),
        max = Math.min(maxSize, a + b);
    int c = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    new Triangle(a, b, x);
}
```

Comment: @durron597 How about this?

Comment: Nice deterministically choosing c. I was too lazy to do the math in my own answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

### An instance variable, or field, is not the same as a local variable.

See: [What is the difference between a local variable, an instance field, an input parameter, and a class field?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20671008/1768232)

You can use local variables just fine, like:

```
public TriangleArray (int number,  int maxSize) {
  list = new Triangle[number];
  for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    list[i] = makeTriangle(maxSize);
   }
}

private makeTriangle(maxSize) {
  Random r = new Random();

  do {
    int first = r.nextInt(maxSize - 1) + 1;
    int second = r.nextInt(maxSize - 1) + 1;
    int third = r.nextInt(maxSize - 1) + 1;

    int max = Math.max(first, Math.max(second, third));
  } while ((2 * max) - first - second - third) > 0);

  return new Triangle(first, second, third);
}
```

In this code you never create a new instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use instance variables to fill in random numbers. You could use your `java.util.Random` or `Math.random`:

```
list = new Triangle[number];
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    int a = (int)(Math.random() * (maxSize + 1));
    int b = (int)(Math.random() * (maxSize + 1));
    int c = (int)(Math.random() * (maxSize + 1));

    //handle the triangle inequality:
    while (c > a + b || c < Math.abs(a - b)) {
        c = (int)(Math.random() * (maxSize + 1));
    }

    list[i] = new Triangle(a, b, c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a `Triangle` object's constructor looks like:

```
public Triangle(int a, int b, int c) { ...
```

We initialize the array with:

```
Random r = new Random(); // random number gen
for ( int i = 0; i < number; i++ ) {
  int a = r.nextInt(maxSize-1) + 1; // randomly generate each side
  int b = r.nextInt(maxSize-1) + 1;
  int c = r.nextInt(maxSize-1) + 1; // this won't necessarily make a proper triangle
  list[i] = new Triangle(a, b, c);
}
```

We have to create a random number generator, then we have to iterate through the entire array of uncreated Triangles and create them. While iterating, we randomly generate each side a, b, and c, to a number from 1 to maxSize, then create the Triangle object at the current index.

The `list` is your instance variable, meanwhile the variables a, b, c, and r are all local variables to the constructor or whatever function you put them in.

Comment: These triangles might not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: True, but that's not the question at hand.