# How can i use a constructor variable in other methods of same class?

Tags: java

I have a constructor with variable initial_Age

```
public Person(int initial_Age) {
    if(initial_Age<0){
        age=0;
    }
```

I want to use initial_Age in other methods but it is giving error(variable not initialized)

```
public void amIOld() {
    if(this.initial_Age>0){
        age=this.initial_Age;
    }
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Use an [instance variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686488/java-what-is-an-instance-variable).

Comment: Thats a `local variable` it can only be used locally where it was declared in a method/constructor. Use a `instance Variable` it can be accessed any constructor or method or any instance as long as it is `public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```
private int initial_Age;

public Person(int initial_Age) {
 this.initial_Age =initial_Age;
  if(initial_Age<0){
    age=0;
 }
```

And you can use `initial_Age` everywhere in the `Person` class.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question.

```
public class Person {
    private int age;

    public Person(int initialAge) {
        this.age = Math.max(initialAge, 0);
    }

    public boolean amIOld() {
        return this.age > 0;
    }
}
```

This way the age for one person is constant. U will need to change the logic.

Comment: I hope you will find the changed answer as more helpful.