# Get Data of List of Objects

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created an input class like 3 inputs Map: `String`, `List`, `List`, 
and then use it in a RecyclerView.
In my constructor, I input strings in the list then clear it, so I have to get my data from the `mainExampleClass`

How can I access it? For instance, in the List which contains the Examples List

```
List<Example> exampleList;
exampleList.get(0);
```

how could I access the data after `get(i)`?

The RecylerView Data object:

```
public class Example {
    private static MainExampleObject exampleObject;
    private static String StepName;
    private static List<String> TemporaryCode = new ArrayList<>(), TemporaryExplanation = new ArrayList<>();

    public Example(MainExampleObject exampleObject) {
        this.exampleObject = exampleObject;
    }

    public static void addCode(String code) {
        TemporaryCode.add(code);
    }

    public static void addExplanation(String explanation) {
        TemporaryExplanation.add(explanation);
    }

    public static void setStepName(String stepName) {
        StepName = stepName;
    }

    public static MainExampleObject getExampleObject() {
        return exampleObject;
    }

    static List<String> getTemporaryCode() {
        return TemporaryCode;
    }

    static List<String> getTemporaryExplanation() {
        return TemporaryExplanation;
    }

    static String getStepName() {
        return StepName;
    }

    public static void addExample(){
        exampleObject = new MainExampleObject(StepName, TemporaryCode, TemporaryExplanation);
        TemporaryCode.clear();
        TemporaryExplanation.clear();
    }

}
```

The example object class:

```
class MainExampleObject {
    private static String StepName;
    private static List<String> Code, Explanation;

    MainExampleObject(String stepHeader, List<String> code, List<String> explanation) {
        StepName = stepHeader;
        Code = code;
        Explanation = explanation;
    }

    public static String getStepNamex() {
        return StepName;
    }

}
```

---

More Details

The method by which I add the data to the list

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Example.setStepName(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getKey()));

                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.child("Code").getChildren()) {
                    Example.addCode(String.valueOf(childSnapshot.getValue()));
                }

                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.child("Explaination").getChildren()) {
                    Example.addExplanation(String.valueOf(childSnapshot.getValue()));
                }
                addExample();
                exampleList.add(new Example(getExampleObject()));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

The Adapter

```
List<Example> exampleList;
    ViewLesson viewLesson;

    public interface OnItemSelectedListenerCustom {
        void onItemClicked(int selectedPosition);
    }

    public class ExampleHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {  // here is where you define what text have value
        CardView cv;
        LinearLayout ll;

        public ExampleHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CV);
            ll = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CV_LL);
        }
    }

    public ExampleAdapter(ViewLesson viewLesson, List<Example> exampleList) {
        this.viewLesson = viewLesson;
        this.exampleList = exampleList;
    }


    @Override
    public ExampleHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
        return new ExampleHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ExampleHolder holder, int position) {

        TextView tv = new TextView(holder.cv.getContext());
        if (Example.getStepName() != null) {
            tv.setText(Example.getStepName());
            holder.ll.addView(tv);
        }

        if (Example.getTemporaryCode() != null && Example.getTemporaryExplanation() != null) {
            int i = 0;
            for (String code : Example.getTemporaryCode()) {
                tv = new TextView(holder.cv.getContext());
                tv.setText(code);
                holder.ll.addView(tv);

                tv = new TextView(holder.cv.getContext());
                tv.setText(Example.getTemporaryCode().get(i));
                holder.ll.addView(tv);
                i++;
            }
            tv = new TextView(holder.cv.getContext());
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(exampleList.get(0).getClass().toString()));
            holder.ll.addView(tv);

            tv = new TextView(holder.cv.getContext());
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(exampleList.get(1).getClass().toString()));
            holder.ll.addView(tv);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return exampleList.size();
    }
}
```

This is the exactly line that I want to get this example of data in separately

```
StepName = 2 Adding b, TemporaryCode = [1aaaa, 2baaa, 3caaa], TemporaryExplanation = [1sttt, 2nddd, 3rddd]
```

where

- the string is `2 Adding b`
- the 1st List is `[1aaaa, 2baaa, 3caaa]`
- the 2nd List is `[1sttt, 2nddd, 3rddd]`

The Line

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(exampleList.get(0).getClass().toString()));
```

Comment: Please see about a [mcve]. Where is the recyclerview? Where is the adapter? Where do you need the data? Do you  understand what `static` actually does?

Comment: Why do you have so many static methods? I suggest you take a few minutes to learn what `static` means.

Comment: @cricket_007 so sorry I thought that the code I posted in enough for the problem and I have added more details to the post, see it please

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I wasn't using sharing my methods with static but using it as 'Example.addCode' for example must be with static

Comment: getClass is a Java method of all objects... Why are you calling that?

Comment: I was just trying to access the data not a part of the main code, its a try

Comment: But why are you doing `Example.addCode()`? You should create instances of your class and call methods on those instances.

Comment: Take a step back from Android and learn more about basic Java instance variables and getters and setters

Comment: @Code-Apprentice How could I do it to the list another way

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you for suggesting that but I have tried this code on my own after learning some basics and posting the question to understand what's wrong

Comment: The immediate problem (with your question) is you've not described what you are seeing being displayed in your app, add where you need it to change

Comment: sorry about that and thank you for your help

Comment: You need to continue learning more of the fundamentals of Java. Specifically, you should study the difference between instance and static variables. You should also read about creating and using instances if a class.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank so, I will read and learn about those topics, appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this line seems you want a String representation of all the variables in your class.

```
 exampleList.get(0).getClass().toString()
```

Well, `getClass()` returns you a Java Class variable, and toString on a `Class` tells nothing about its fields.

Please see [How to override toString() properly in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java) and apply it to your class **after** you fix whatever you did to think you needed `static` everywhere

If done correctly, this would work.

```
 setText(String.valueOf(exampleList.get(0)))
```

Comment: thank you so much, I will try this, also if you added another reference of not using the static in setters and getter that will be nice

Comment: static values are called class variables. They are shared by all instances http://stackoverflow.com/a/16686545/2308683