# How to resolve the "Make field an instance variable" issue?

Tags: java, sonarqube

SonarQube 5.5 (with the `sonar-java-plugin-3.13.1.jar` plugin) reports an issue on this code:

```
public class TimeA {
    public static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMATTER;

    static {
        SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        DATE_FORMATTER=df;
    }
}
```

The error message is `Make "DATE_FORMATTER" an instance variable.`

How can I avoid this SonarQube issue?

Comment: This post explains what an instance variable is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686488/java-what-is-an-instance-variable

Comment: The versions of SonarQube and SonarJava plugin you are using are quite old. You should update to the more recent versions.

Answer (score 7):

In the above class, `SonarQube` is trying to say that `DATE_FORMATTER` does not need to be static if it is not used by any `static` method.

In fact, `SimpleDateFormat` should not be an instance variable as well, as it's not thread safe (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021151/java-dateformat-is-not-threadsafe-what-does-this-leads-to)). If multiple threads are accessing methods of `TimeA` class simultaneously then it will lead to incorrect result.

If the format is same then you can declare it as a `final String` and create `SimpleDateFormat` instances locally, e.g.:

```
public final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";

public void someMethod(){
    SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    //Further processing
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Got it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For the logs, if you have performance constraints, you can also consider using `ThreadLocal` to store one date format per thread.